# lambda function not accepting mapping regulation via input (Python)

Tags: python, lambda, calculus

How can I make a function in the lambda form accept a mapping regulation via input instead of explicitly stating it in the function?

Here is my code, I am trying to create a program for nummerical integration.

```
while True:

 fx=input("Enter a function: ")
 a=int(input("Choose lower integration limit: "))
 b=int(input("Choose upper integration limit: "))
 delta=float(input("Choose delta x: "))

 step=int(1/delta)

 interval=list(range((a*step),(b*step)))
 f= lambda x: (x**2)*delta
```

> Now I want to substitute this part `(x**2)` for an arbitray polynomial via the input `fx`

```
 result=map(f,interval)
 print(sum(list(result))*(delta**2))


continue
```

if i try substituting `(x**2)` for `fx` it will produce this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\Python-Programme\Nummerische         Integration.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(sum(list(result))*(delta**2))
  File "C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\Python-Programme\Nummerische    Integration.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    f= lambda x: fx*delta
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

*I am fully aware that this is probably not an optimal program for nummerical integration, the reason why im building this is just to exercise my programming skills while making programs that I still could theoreticaly use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding of the question if this makes sense, the error comes from a type mismatch:

When you get the input from `fx=input("Enter a function: ")` the variable fx will be of type `str`. Try `print(type(fx))`.

When you then perform `fx*delta` you basically try to multiply a string with a numerical value, which does not make sense. Thus your Error `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`.

A quick solution would be

```
while True:
    n=int(input("Enter degree of polynomial: "))
    print(type(fx))
    a=int(input("Choose lower integration limit: "))
    b=int(input("Choose upper integration limit: "))
    delta=float(input("Choose delta x: "))
    step=int(1/delta)
    interval=list(range((a*step),(b*step)))
    f= lambda x: (x**n)*delta
    result=map(f,interval)
    print(sum(list(result))*(delta**2))
    continue
```

An advanced solution would need a way to parse your string input into a lambda function, which I think is not that easy.

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
f = lambda x: fx(x) * delta
```

what you want?

Then you have to enter `lambda x: x**2` for fx.

But maybe it is a bit too early for advanced concepts like functional programming, as Python tries not to put too much emphasis on them? You could start for example, by making this piece of your code much nicer and correct for any function.

```
step=int(1/delta)
interval=list(range((a*step),(b*step)))
result=map(f,interval)
print(sum(list(result))*(delta**2))
```